# 提交给 vs 提交 difference

Tags: word-choice, difference, simplified-characters

What's the difference between :
提交给 and 提交?

What does 给 indicate when it follows words like 提交, 借, etc.?

And should I use 把 whenever I use words like "return", "submit", "hand over", etc.?

Answer (score 2):

1. 提交 is merely an action. 提交给 requires a word to refer to the person who review/read the thing you submitted.
2. 给 means "to" in English. When it appears right after 提交, 借 etc., it needs you to provide a word right after 给 to refer to the person that you **submit [sth.] to** or **lend [sth.] to**
3. 把 is used in some expression like "send the book to you" which could be translated to "把 书交给你". Usually the word “把” does not have an explicit correspondence in English. For those words you've give, you could use “把” when you mean "return/submit something to someone". In other words, if you want to state the receiver, then you should use 给.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! You've been a big help!

Comment: By the way, I want to ask, do I still need to add 给 when I use this word : 还?

Comment: @Agnes yeah, you need to. Although it could be omitted in informal oral expressions.

Comment: @Agnes For example, 我来还你书 is totally acceptable in oral expressions, which could be translated to "i come here to return you the book".

Comment: @Agnes My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have sufficient reputation points to comment so I am answering your question here).

RE: By the way, I want to ask, do I still need to add 给 when I use this word : 还?
Yes, you can add 给, but it's not 100% necessary.

For example, I return the book to you:
below are all valid translations
我把书还给你
我把书还你
我还你书
我还给你书

but these are incorrect ones: 
我还你把书
我还给你把书
。。。